# column A has 3 same values and need to check column B values for the same column A

Tags: oracle

For example, I have column A Department and column B as employee type, I need to check the following.

```
Department    Emp Type  
Dep1            S  
Dep1            H  
Dep1            P  
Dep2            H  
Dep2            H  
Dep2            H
```

I need to retrieve the departments only with H employee type for all the 3 rows. If the emp types are different I need to ignore that department.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Department
FROM tableX  t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM tableX  s
        WHERE s.Department = t.Department
          AND s.EmpType <> 'H'
      ) ;
```

If you have an index on `(Department, EmpType)`, the fastest way is probably:

```
SELECT Department
FROM tableX  t
GROUP BY Department
HAVING MIN(EmpType) = 'H'
   AND MAX(EmpType) = 'H' ;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use a group by with having to filter out the ones with only H:

```
SQL> create table dept(dep varchar2(5), typ varchar2(1));

Table created.

SQL> insert into dept
  2  select 'Dep1', 'S' from dual union all
  3  select 'Dep1', 'H' from dual union all
  4  select 'Dep1', 'P' from dual union all
  5  select 'Dep2', 'H' from dual union all
  6  select 'Dep2', 'H' from dual union all
  7  select 'Dep2', 'H' from dual;

6 rows created.

SQL> select dep
  2    from dept
  3   group by dep
  4   having count(distinct typ) = 1
  5      and max(typ) = 'H';

DEP
-----
Dep2
```